# Copy pictures from ubuntu folder to google drive folder

Tags: server, backup, cron, steam, google-drive

I am trying to make a crontab schedule to copy all picture files - steam screenshots - to my google drive account, then back them up to my home server.

So far I have "cp - R /home/(user)/Pictures/Screenshots/Steam/ gio google-drive://(user)@gmail.com/Screenshots/Steam/" but this outputs "cp: target '(URL)' is not a directory".

Has anyone done this before? I have searched the web some but found little up-to-date and working information.

Comment: Note: I cannot or cannot see an option to simply save my steam screenshots to my google drive folder.

Answer (score 0):

> `cp - R /home/(user)/Pictures/Screenshots/Steam/ gio google-drive://(user)@gmail.com/Screenshots/Steam/" but this outputs "cp: target '(URL)' is not a directory`

There's space on your directory and option, it should be.

```
cp -R /home/(user)/Pictures/Screenshots/Steam/gio google-drive://(user)@gmail.com/Screenshots/Steam/
```

Notice that I remove the space on `Steam/ gio` and `cp - R`.

If your picture collection growing over time, I suggest rsync— you can setup it to only copy new files so you don't have to overwrite existing files.

```
rsync -ca --ignore-existing /home/(user)/Pictures/Screenshots/Steam/gio google-drive://(user)@gmail.com/Screenshots/Steam/
```

This will only transfer new screenshot that don't exist on destination (your google drive).